# Avoiding overshoot in step response for robustness

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback, stability

In Systematic Design of Analog CMOS Circuits (Jespsers, Murmann) page 343, the following is stated in the context of where to place the non-dominant pole in a second-order loop transfer function of a switched-capacitor amplifier:

> The case of ωp2/ωu1 = 4 (Q = 0.5) results in a critically damped step response. This corresponds to the fastest possible settling without overshoot [7] and is the preferred choice for SC [switched capacitor] circuits that are designed for maximum speed. *Designing for ωp2/ωu1 < 4 is not recommended to avoid overshoot, which is difficult to manage if the goal is to create a robust design.*

The emphasis is mine, and also see the figure below if helpful. Note that the reference [7] in the quote is [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/52726). (I don't think this paper addresses my question, below).

My questions are:

1. Why is overshoot "difficult to manage" in a "robust" design?
2. What are the main problems that overshoot could cause? The above quote comes from the context of switched-capacitor circuits, so that may be relevant. The main thing I can think of is maybe the overshoot could result in dropping the output stage devices / input devices of the next stage out of saturation if the overshoot makes the signal swing too big, I'm unsure if this is one such problem / if there are others.

[image: loop gain unity crossover]

Comment: Your final paragraph (the question) appears to be mixing up "why is it difficult to manage" with "what problems it may cause". This makes it difficult to make a coherent answer.

Comment: @Andyaka Alright, I will separate the questions out more explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A robust design implies that the circuit is highly tolerant to component-to-component variation. The Q=0.5 condition is the theoretical limit that can be achieved without overshoot while minimizing the settling time (fastest response). The issue is that slight variation (tolerances) could cause Q>0.5 which results overshoot in the response. Some applications can't tolerate any overshoot for any duration. This is why you don't want to place the pole at the limit when you are trying to achieve a robust design. In practice, you would want to shift the pole a bit to the left (Q<0.5) to assure you have adequate damping (at the expense of speed) to mitigate any overshoot over all operating conditions.

In other words, it's a sensitive balance between performance (fast response) and robustness (insensitive to component values).

Comment: For a 2nd order system, spectral gain peaking occurs when Q exceeds \$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\$. Overshoot in the time domain occurs when Q exceeds 0.5

Comment: @Andyaka You are correct. I flipped the signs. Answer now corrected. I had damping on my my mind.

Comment: Still incorrect. Gain peaking (in the bode plot) occurs when Q is greater than 0.7071.

Comment: @MOSFET Thanks for the answer, I'm wondering could you elaborate a bit more on what kinds of applications have no tolerance for overshoot and why not?

Comment: @Halleff Sure. Consider stabilizing a nuclear power plant reactor with control rods. If you remove the rods too fast (overshoot) you may never recover and the result will be a meltdown. The ABS on a car are tuned aggressively for fast braking but still overdamped - overshoot here would result in the brakes locking so it has to be avoided. CNC cutting tool servos can't tolerate overshoot when changing positions or it would result in the cutting tool crashing into the workpiece. But they have to be tuned aggressively as possible for speed without compromising the positional accuracy.